# sorting search results with php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search-engine

Using a search result from mysql, how can I sort the results with php to show the closest matches first?

i.e. a user searches for "keyword" and I have 50 results containing "keyword" from different tables and fields in my database. They all match. I want to show results that have the exact match "keyword" first and other matches after:

```
1 = "keyword in this result"
2 = "keyword in 10th result"
3 = "keywords in 5th result"
4 = "has keyword in 3rd result"
5 = "this has the keyword in the 8th result"
6 = "this has mykeyword in the 40th result"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well once you get your recordset back to PHP you could sort the array easily however you want with `usort()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
<?php
$keyword = 'foobar';
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strpos($a, $keyword) == strpos($b, $keyword)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strpos($a, $keyword) < strpos($b, $keyword)) ? -1 : 1;
}

$arr = $my_recordset;
usort($arr, "cmp");

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

That matches the keyword position in strings so more relevant strings would show up higher. A little recursion and modification to this idea could be easily implemented into your application.

Comment: Another approach might also be the Levenshtein distance (http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), so you could sort by the ascending distance. Not sure if this exactly matches the problem though...

Comment: Levenshtein is for misspellings. Take the string "Cars" - levenshtein would find words that it thinks you meant based on a 'distance' from the word: "crash, care, scar" etc.

Comment: sorry - reading the documentation now on multidimensional array usort :-)